# How to return Google Sheets data from Apps Script webapp?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have A1:E2 range of values in data variable (just two rows). But when I send a GET request I see the message:

> "The script completed but did not return anything."

Help me please find a mistake.

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.p1 == "getRow")
    getRow();
}

function getRow() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("...");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:E2");
  var data = range.getValues();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: I think that in your script, ``doGet()`` doesn't return values. So how about modifying to ``if (e.parameter.p1 == "getRow") return getRow();``? When you modified the script, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps.

Comment: Thank you. But doGet() doesn't have to return any data. It's here just to run getRow(), that must return data in json format.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. My comment is for the message of ``But when I send a GET request I see the message: "The script completed but did not return anything.".`` in your question. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me.

Comment: You understood correctly.

Comment: @Neret, the value of a function is only returned to the calling scope. So you need to review JavaScript functions, and the Apps Script web app documentation.

Comment: Further, anyone reading your code might wonder why your `getRow` function returns not a row number, but JSON. Consider only returning UI-specific types from functions that are invoked and supposed to return those types (e.g. `doGet` and `doPost`). This will let you use `getRow` from other parts of your code.

Comment: `doGet()` executes `getRow()`. `getRow()` answers only to `doGet()`. `doGet()` receives the answer  from `getRow` and does nothing. Get it?

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not sure what should I change here. Could you write the right answer?

Comment: The very first comment has the right answer with code.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!